# Behaviour of try-with-resources with closable parameters

Tags: java, try-with-resources

Does Java-7's try-with-resources require the closable to be assigned directly to a variable? In short, is this block of code...

```
    try (final ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(
            new ByteArrayInputStream(data))) {
        return ois.readObject();
    }
```

Equivalent to this block?...

```
    try (final ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
         final ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(in)) {
        return ois.readObject();
    }
```

My understanding of Section 14.20.3 of the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/jls7.pdf) says they are not the same and the resources must be assigned. This would be surprising from a common usage standpoint and I can't find any documentation warning against the pattern.

Comment: wouldn't returning that object hold it's reference open (and thus not allow GC)?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis you'll notice I referenced that same content in my question...

Comment: @AndrewWhite Haha, I guess I  misunderstood your question. Tavian seems to say it best.

Comment: @SnakeDoc It's not the streams which are returned, and in any case try-with-resources is orthogonal to GC. You can close something without it getting garbage collected. It exists in the first place because the GC is not very good at cleaning up these resources.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two blocks are not equivalent in the sense that they won't generate the same code.  But since `ObjectInputStream.close()` will call `close()` on the `ByteArrayInputStream` that you passed it, the first block is completely fine.

EDIT: Something I forgot is that unlike reasonable constructions like `new BufferedInputStream(new *InputStream(...))`, the `ObjectInputStream` constructor actually reads from the stream you pass it and thus could reasonably throw an exception.  For that reason I'd actually recommend the second block, not the first block.

Comment: What if `new ObjectInputStream` throws?

Comment: @delnan Very good point, I forgot that the `ObjectInputStream` constructor actually reads from the stream.

Answer (score 2):

The code is not the same as you already mentioned, as Java will generate a close block for each variable even though it is not necessary. What is more important is this comment from the JavaDocs on AutoCloseable:

> Note that unlike the close method of Closeable, this close method is
>   not required to be idempotent. In other words, calling this close
>   method more than once may have some visible side effect, unlike
>   Closeable.close which is required to have no effect if called more
>   than once. However, implementers of this interface are strongly
>   encouraged to make their close methods idempotent.

Basically it means that calling `close()` twice *should* not have any effect, but it is not guaranteed. So it is recommended to avoid the 2nd construct you presented to avoid calling close twice.

Comment: Note that the `close()` methods of `ObjectInputStream` and `ByteArrayInputStream` *are* idempotent, so in this case that doesn't matter.  (Actually, the `close()` method of `ByteArrayInputStream` doesn't do anything at all.)

Answer (score 1):

Always use the second form. In the first form "new ObjectInputStream()" will throw an exception if the array is empty. This will leave 
the ByteArrayInputStream open.